# Are Next.js and Gatsby.js using the split code Loadable Component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, gatsby, loadable-component

Are Next.js and Gatsby.js using the split code Loadable Component ?

The loadable component I am talking about is the one recommended by the Facebook team https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components

I am lazy at searching this.

If you reply I'll give points.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using npm, you may find that out by doing a deep search of dependency tree on your Next.js or Gatsby projects using the `npm ls` command.

Neither the latest version of Next.js, nor Gatsby use the package you specified.

Next.js implements this feature with [dynamic imports](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import).

And Gatsby has a separate plugin for the job: [gatsby-plugin-loadable-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-loadable-components).

Comment: Many thanks, very interesting

Comment: Next.js has reinvented something already existing